# Using the correct settings constant in Django view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-settings

I am moderatly experienced with Django and am setting up a new project using the now recommended "multiple settings files" pattern. Each settings.py file will import a base settings.py and then override specific setting. There will be one file for each staging environment (dev, qa, prod). When starting the Django process, I am making sure to set the settings flag to the appropriate settings.py file like so

```
manage.py runserver --settings=myproj.settings.dev
```

or

```
manage.py runfcgi --settings=myproj.settings.prod method=threaded daem...[more flags]
```

My question is, how do I get an environment specific constant into my view's functions. I have some specific constants (curl cert/host/port) for my project that are different for each environment. Currently I have only figured out how to include the environment in the import path, but this won't work for me, if someone can please help that would be awesome.

Here is an example views.py file that should help make my question a little clearer.

```
# A sample Django view.py file

from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from myproj import settings

def index(request):
    # these assignments work, but I have to add conditional logic to pick the correct
    # value, I would prefer not to do this.
    dev_curl_host = settings.dev.CONNECT['host']
    qa_curl_host = settings.qa.CONNECT['host']
    prod_curl_host = settings.prod.CONNECT['host']

    # I want to do something like this, where the settings import get assigned the 
    # correct values for the staging environment.
    # It seems like Django is already doing this with settings like Debug, how?
    curl_host = settings.CONNECT['host']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
from myproj import settings
```

do

```
from django.conf import settings
```

That's why DEBUG works:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code

Comment: Picking this answer, although the one below is also correct, because it was submitted first and the link to django docs was also very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @macguru2000 sure, by the way, you should definitely read "Settings and Requirements Files" chapter from [Two Scoops of Django](https://django.2scoops.org/) book - it's exactly on the subject of this thread.

Comment: I am actually reading that book now, so far I'm very happy with it, but I must have missed the area where it mentions getting settings from django.conf. Totally makes sense now that I know though. Thanks!